# LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN in one query

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables : `courses`, `users`, `course_ratings` ( this table has foreign keys to users and courses and and the column `rating` containing the user's rating for the course )

I want to get all the courses, even those not related to the `course_ratings` table but if this course is related then I want to get average rating and count of all users associated with this course. This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT c.title, COALESCE (AVG(cr.rating), 0), COUNT(u.user_id) 
FROM courses c
LEFT JOIN course_ratings cr ON c.course_id = cr.course_id
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = cr.user_id
GROUP BY c.course_id;
```

As you can see I try to get even those courses that do not have any rate and assign them a rating of 0. But as a result, I only have courses that have at least one rating.

Comment: Make the `JOIN users` a LEFT JOIN also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two `left join`s:

```
SELECT c.title, COALESCE(AVG(cr.rating), 0), COUNT(u.user_id) 
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN 
     course_ratings cr
     ON c.course_id = cr.course_id LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.user_id = cr.user_id
GROUP BY c.title;
```

I changed the `GROUP BY` column to match the `SELECT`.

Do note that you do not actually need the `users` table:

```
SELECT c.title, COALESCE(AVG(cr.rating), 0), COUNT(cr.user_id) 
FROM courses c LEFT JOIN 
     course_ratings cr
     ON c.course_id = cr.course_id 
GROUP BY c.title;
```

The information you need is actually in `course_ratings` (well, assuming that all `user_id`s in that table are valid, which seems like a reasonable assumption).

Comment: If this code were yours, would you choose the first or second option from your answer?

Comment: @Monoxyd . . . I would choose the second option.  Why bother with a `JOIN` if it is not necessary?